# Print subset of file from line number to first match of regex using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to print the content of a file starting a particular line number till the first occurrence of a pattern and immediately stop the search & print. I tried this one:

```
sed -n '2,/{p; :loop n; p; /pattern/q; b loop}'
```

but without success. How can this be achieved?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed: to stop after a line containg pattern:

```
sed -n '2,/pattern/{p;/pattern/q;} file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '2,/pattern/p' file
```

Or this awk command:

```
awk 'NR==2{p=1} p; /pattern/{exit}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '2,/pattern/!d;//q' file
```